# How to propagate a text value to SF managed package subscribers?

Tags: oauth2, 2gp

We have a 2G Managed Package which needs to be integrated with an external system via OAuth 2.0 flow to push/pull data from. In other words, SF managed package is supposed to pull data from and push data to the external system using the API, which requires authorization. This external system has a strict security policy that requires consumer secrets to be rotated every six months. We want all SF app subscribers to reflect consumer key rotation with a minimum impact so that OAuth 2.0 flow continues functioning.

Here is what I've already thought through:

- **Feature Management (LMO to subscriber)** seems to be not an option because of only Boolean, Integer, and Date data types are supported.
- **A new package version being released every 6 months** with an updated secret is not an option as well.

  - Simply requesting all the subscribers to upgrade every 6 months is ridiculous.
  - Pushing upgrades is not an option because of there are too many subscribers on too many different package versions. Upgrade between some of the versions requires manual post-upgrade steps to be done, so it can't be fully automated.
- **An additional package that only stores consumer secret** seems to be the best option as of now. The installation of this package will be required in order to use the main app (otherwise, you won't be able to establish a connection with the external system). It's simple to push the upgrade every 6 months, cause the upgrade itself doesn't require any manual user interaction. The only complexity is explaining to the hundreds of enterprise clients that they now have to install this additional package to make the main one work. Moreover, the solution itself looks odd.

*Are there any other creative ideas you can come up with? Or is there some simple solution I'm missing out? Thanks in advance!*